# Help interpreting strange pattern in PCA

Tags: pca

This is likely a naive question about principle coordinate analysis, but my googling skills are failing me in this instance. I've conducted PCA on a multidimensional dataset, and got this result:

[image]

My experience working with data makes me immediately suspicious of that long trailing line of points, but I'm new to PCA and am not sure how/if it is an issue or what might be causing it. I've already removed co-correlated variables and have z-score standardized the remaining variables prior to conducting the PCA. Trying min/max normalization also did not change this result. Does anyone have any insight about what might be going on here?

Here are the loadings of the PCs:

[image]

And here is a header of the z-score standardized data used to create the PCA:

[image]

Comment: What's the contribution of the predictor $k$ to PC1 and to PC2? (I think that's the predictor name, it's hard to be sure from the plot--I'm talking about the one whose direction is more or less parallel to your "long trailing line of points.")

Comment: The long line is likely the result of 0s in your data (which you haven't told us anything about) which doesn't have any negative values. Does this sound like a reasonable description of your data?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments! @EdM, yes k is the predictor name. It contributes -0.2851868 to PC1 and 0.89974582 PC2 respectively. It seems to be contributing highly to PC2 with not a lot of contribution from other variables, could that explain what I'm seeing? I'll add more detailed info in the original post.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson, there are actually no 0s in this data, and there are frequent negative values in the non-normalized and normalized data. The data consists of 85 points with four predictor variables. The predictor variables describe microbial death dynamics in various ways. I'll add some previews of the data to the original post in case that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the arrows and principal-component loadings indicate, a change of one unit in $k$ represents different directions of change in PC1 and PC2, with the magnitude of the change about 3 times more for PC2 than for PC1. That describes your "long trailing line of points."

As values of $k$ change while other things are held constant (or while there are offsetting changes in `change_abund` and `end_abund`, whose arrows are pretty much opposite in direction to each other and orthogonal to the $k$ direction in the plot), an increase of 0.1 units in PC1 due to a change in $k$ will be associated with a decrease of about 0.3 units in PC2. That's what you see.

The data would probably show that those points in the line either have similar values for predictors other than $k$ or offsetting differences in `change_abund` and `end_abund`.

With so few predictors and data points, it's not clear that working with principal components analysis is going to be of much help. You are probably better off doing a standard regression rather than working with principal components. Then coefficients would also have interpretations that are easier to understand and to explain to others.